# CodeCeption Laravel Unit Testing issue

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, codeception

I am using codeception, I have the following code :

```
public function testValidation()
{
    $user = User::create();

    $user->username = null;
    $this->assertFalse($user->validate(['username']));

    $user->username = 'John';
    $this->assertFalse($user->validate(['username']));

    $user->username = 'Jim';
    $this->assertTrue($user->validate(['username']));
}
```

I have included `use App\User` on the top.

Am i missing something ?

The Error it throws :

`[Error] Call to a member function connection() on null`

Comment: Not enought information, please run codeception with -vvv flag and add a complete stacktrace to your question.

Comment: It looks like an unrelated stacktrace of composer error.